# Proving the compound angle formula for: $\sin(a+b)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, triangles

So I am currently trying to prove the compound angle formula for $\sin$. Here is what I have attempted so far:

[image]

From the picture about(not very well drawn(I know!)),

- I find that $\angle EAD = \angle GBF = \beta$

So...

$\sin(\alpha + \beta) = \frac{BC}{BA} = \frac{CH+HB}{BA} = \frac{CH}{BA} + \frac{HB}{BA}$

$\sin(\alpha) = \frac{GB}{BA}$

$\sin(\beta) = \frac{ED}{EA} = \frac{GH}{GB} = \frac{HF}{GF}$

$\cos(\alpha) = \frac{GA}{BA}$

$\cos(\beta) = \frac{DA}{EA} = \frac{HB}{GB} = \frac{GH}{GF}$

Now, looking at the denominators for $\sin(\alpha + \beta)$ and for $\sin(\alpha)$, I found a way to sneak in latter into the first equation by:

$\frac{HB}{BA} = \frac{HB*GB}{BA*GB} = \frac{GB}{BA} * \frac{HB}{GB} = \sin(\alpha)\cos(\beta)$

I can already see the second half of the equation starting to come out. I am currently stuck on the first half of the equation, I have tried to manipulate to allow access for $\sin(\beta)$ or $\cos(\alpha)$ but I am not getting anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there. The trick to calculate $\frac{CH}{BA}$ is to drop a perpendicular from $G$ to meet segment $AD$ at point $J$ (say). Now notice that $CH$ has the same length as $JG$, and compute
$$\frac{CH}{BA}=\frac{JG}{BA}=\frac{JG}{GA}\frac{GA}{BA}=\sin(\beta)\cos(\alpha).$$